# Parallel option for vstest.console.exe does not work as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, async-await, mstest

I am expecting vstest.console.exe will run all test methods in parallel with `/Parallel` option specified. On a 4 core machine, I am expecting below test class will cost around 2~3 seconds for execution, by actually I got 8~9 seconds which means the tests are executed sequentially.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod3()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod4()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

The test ouput:

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.5.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... Passed   TestMethod1 Passed
>   TestMethod2 Passed   TestMethod3 Passed   TestMethod4
>
> Total tests: 4. Passed: 4. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0. Test Run Successful.
>
> Test execution time: 8.6960 Seconds

Comment: Do you have a settings file that you're using? The complete command line (+ settings, if applicable) would be useful to make sure people can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: `vstest.console.exe /Parallel MyUnitTest.dll` produces the above result. Noticed I got same execution time with/without /Parallel option, looks it does not have any effect.

Comment: Not played with this much myself. But it appears when this feature was introduced that it could parallelize only across test containers - i.e. if you have multiple *assemblies* it will run the tests in the separate assemblies in parallel. Can't see anything that suggests that anything has changed since then.

Answer (score 3):

You will be needing a setting file inorder to tell how many core you want to use for the execution.

command will be something like this:

```
vstest.console.exe /Parallel MyUnitTest.dll /Settings:C:\Settings.testsettings
```

And the Settings.testsettings should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
<RunConfiguration>
<MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
</RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

The value for MaxCpuCount has the following semantics:

‘n’ (where 1 <= n <= number of cores): upto ‘n’ processes will be launched.
‘n’ of any other value: The number of processes launched will be as many as the available cores on the machine.
Typically, a value of 0 indicates that up to all of the available free cores may be used.

Comment: Does not work, at least when file was renamed to .runsettings and selected from Visual studio IDE. Should it work ?

Comment: Ah, this works only when you have two unit test projects, they ran in parallel, but not only for one unit test project.